# OpenSSL required for laravel project, enbaled in php.ini, but not working?

Tags: laravel, openssl, composer-php, php-openssl, php-8.2

**In Factory.php line 648:**

The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not availab
le. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disable this error
, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.

**terminal output:**

```
php -i | grep openssl  
OpenSSL support => disabled (install ext/openssl)  
OLDPWD => /home/Merlin/openssl-3.0.8  
$_SERVER['OLDPWD']=> /home/Merlin/openssl-3.0.8  
$_ENV['OLDPWD'] => /home/Merlin/openssl-3.0.8
```

php version : 8.2
composer version : 2.5.8
I have enabled the openssl in the php.ini and still not working

Comment: Please add the output of `composer diagnose` to your question be editing it. Additionally you need to install the openssl extension for that php version you're executing as well, as the output shows. We don't know in which php.ini file you have edited what nor if that php.ini file applies to that php binary you're executing and if that php cli version _has_ the openssl extension, which is a prerequisite to enable it per php.ini.

Comment: "OpenSSL support => disabled" - that does not look like you've enabled the extension properly. **How** did you enable it? And how is this a problem related to Laravel?